# Dock preferences not saved

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, dock

Ive been rattled out of my mind for the past few days. What started the issue was a random kernel panic that rest all my dock settings. initially i thought it would be due fixed on restart, however no preferences are saved at all.

Steps i have tried

I ran Killall Dock but it just resets it to default. 
Tried to locate com.apple.Dock.plist and delete it but initially there was no file which is strange. So i copied the sc from the apple website and recreated the file and placed it in ./library/application support/dock
Still no solution

another thing to note was that my VsCode was giving me a write error to the same folder which i fixed by deleting the old code folder

Specs: MBA 2015 on High Sierra

Comment: Have you run First Aid from Disk Utility yet? That would seem an obvious first step. Test another account to see if the same happens. Remove any 3rd party kexts. Reinstall the OS from Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin I managed to screw it up even more. I updated to the developer beta 4 and my terminal bricked. Fixed that now and am coming back to this issue

Comment: Well... take solace in the fact it's not the beta 4 itself. I'm on it too, with no real issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one found an answer im gonna post my solution

The initial error that affected a bunch of other applications was a mismatch in the write permissions on the ~/Library/Application Support/ folder I deleted the said folder and restarted the application as the write permissions were not an issue in the get info section

Afterward my terminal froze . so i set it to bash/sh to fix it
KillAll dock and it worked. I cant exaclty explain what the issue was but i suggest that the system couldnt read the com.apple.Dock.plist